# What is the standard way to display a large number of images for each item in my database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm quite inexperienced and I am building a movie database website of roughly 100 movies using node.js, express, and mongoDB. Each movie has roughly 25-30 images, some of which will need captions, as well as a handful of text fields. I am comfortable with adding and storing the text to MongoDB but I'm not sure how to address the image section. I have all of the images stored locally on my device but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Would pushing all of the images into the database be the best way forward? That seems like an unnecessary step, but once again, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Be careful with your wording. This can be taken as a "highly opinion based" question. You might want to ask something more like "what's a standard way to accomplish ____". You might get better answers as well as avoiding down votes as well as close votes.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback I will definitely follow that practice moving forward.

Comment: I didn't think about it earlier, but you also have another problem with your question. You should include what you've already researched, so there's no duplication of effort on our part. It also shows that you've at least tried to figure out the problem before asking. You can also ask about pros/cons about the different techniques you've looked at, but at the same time, that might be too broad, too. SE/SO can be a tough crowd, so it's a line line between a good or bad Question sometimes. And always expect "drive-by" down votes with no explanation why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way is like this. create column image_url like char.
and your code :- before save the image , you need to generate some unique string. then rename your image using that unique string. now you can save your image into any cloud or, your storage path. after image saved, add db record. when you add db record save generated unique string into image_url column in db.

when you retrieve image from db, find your image in your saved storage path using that image_url ( unique string ) ❤️

don’t try to save full image with format in db directly. because it is bad practice.

Comment: I think I'm following but I don't fully understand. For example, the schema for each movie has these following text fields: name, description, production, and remarks. Could I add an array item that would hold these image storage paths (ie /images/movie/picture1)?

Comment: This is definitely one way to accomplish this functionality, but it's not "the best way", since everyone's situation is different. I've worked on systems where having the image in the DB was the best way. I've also done a handful of other ways that worked just as well.